# Angular 9 + Docker Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

У меня есть проблема касающаяся запуска docker контейнера. Имеется dockerfile, который работает у меня на системе.

Сам файл:

```
#############
### build ###
#############

# base image
FROM node:12.2.0 as build

# install chrome for protractor tests
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >>     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9

# add app
COPY . /app

# run tests
#RUN ng test --watch=false
#RUN ng e2e --port 4202

# generate build
RUN ng build --output-path=dist

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Не понятно по какой причине, с помощью этого докерфайла, уже на арендованой VPS тоже с системой Ubuntu он уже запускаться не хочет и выдает такую ошибку:

```
Compiling ng2-smart-table : es2015 as esm2015
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
See "/tmp/ng-IyiTYF/angular-errors.log" for further details.
The command '/bin/sh -c ng build --output-path=dist' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Ну, а в логе-то чё написано?

Comment: Я уже разобрался, и в логах ничего нет.

Comment: Ну тогда напиши в чём была проблема.

Comment: Я увеличил объем оперативной памяти и изменил версию node на 12.10.3